# How to Count clicks on element with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I just created a animation task like simple game. When you click the start game button a circle will appear on random positions at certain intervals. i have tried my best and struggling to do the following tasks :

- Add score +1 while click on the `<p>` (**circle**) element
- Reduce score -1 while clicking rather than the `<p>` (**circle**) element

Thanks in advance.. :)

```js
var windowHeight = 0;
var parendElement;

 function startg () {
    parendElement = document.getElementById("box");
    windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
    document.body.style.height = windowHeight + "px";

    var interval = setInterval(function () {
        generateBall();
    }, 1000);
};

function generateBall() {
    var leftPos = Math.floor((Math.random() * window.innerWidth) - 30);
    var topPos = Math.floor((Math.random() * windowHeight) - 30);
    var para = document.createElement("p");
    para.style.left = leftPos + "px";
    para.style.top = topPos + "px";
    para.setAttribute("class", 'circle');
    parendElement.appendChild(para);
    removeBall(para);
}
function removeBall(ele) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        parendElement.removeChild(ele);
    }, 1000);
}

var clicks= 0;
clicks = document.getElementById('scores').valueOf();

var ballclk = document.getElementsByClassName('circle');
ballclk.onclick = function (){
    clicks++;
    console.log('clicks');
};
```

```css
.circle{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: blueviolet;
}
body{
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
#box{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.score{
    font-size: 18px;
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}
input[type=text]
{
    padding: 5px 5px;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 15px;
    width: 90px;
}
button{
    padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="score">
<button onclick="startg()">Start Game</button>
<label for="scores"><b>Score</b></label>
<input type="text" value="0" name="scores" id="scores">
</div>
<div id="box"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

updated with .stopPropagation() (thank you @xorspark)

Here you go, with -1 for clicks outside the circle, but I don't think this is the right way to do it,
I added 2 instead of 1 to the click event of the circle as a workaround because I couldn't get the selector `body:not(.circle)` to work.

also (as mentioned by @Mykola_Borysyuk) you should use:

```
document.getElementById('scores').value = clicks;
```

instead of

```
clicks = document.getElementById('scores').valueOf();
```

because you're taking the value of clicks and putting it in the input, not the other way around.

good start though :)

```js
var windowHeight = 0;
  var parendElement;
  var clicks = 0;
  clicksInput = document.getElementById('scores');

   function startg () {
      parendElement = document.getElementById("body")
      windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
      document.body.style.height = windowHeight + "px";
   
      var interval = setInterval(function () {
          generateBall();
      }, 1000);
  };

  function generateBall() {
      var leftPos = Math.floor((Math.random() * window.innerWidth) - 30);
      var topPos = Math.floor((Math.random() * windowHeight) - 30);
   document.getElementById('box').onclick = function(e){e.stopPropagation();score('-')}
      var para = document.createElement("p");
      para.style.left = leftPos + "px";
      para.style.top = topPos + "px";
      para.setAttribute("class", 'circle');
      parendElement.appendChild(para);
   para.onclick = function(){score('+')}
   
      removeBall(para);
  }
  function removeBall(ele) {
      setTimeout(function () {
          parendElement.removeChild(ele);
      }, 1000);
  }

  function score(operation) {
   if (operation == '+') {
    clicks++;
    clicksInput.value = clicks;
    console.log('clicks');
   } else {
    clicks--;
    clicksInput.value = clicks;
    console.log('clicks');
   }
  }
```

```css
.circle{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: blueviolet;
}
body{
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
#box{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.score{
    font-size: 18px;
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}
input[type=text]
{
    padding: 5px 5px;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 15px;
    width: 90px;
}
button{
    padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<body id="body">
<div class="score">
<button onclick="startg()">Start Game</button>
<label for="scores"><b>Score</b></label>
<input type="text" value="0" name="scores" id="scores">
</div>
<div id="box"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: You can just call `stopPropagation` on the click event so you don't have to add twice.

Answer (score 3):

To expand on Mykola's answer, not only do you need to set the value in the field itself, but you also need to create the  `onclick` event as you're creating the ball in `generateBall()` for it to work. Also the return value of `valueOf()` is the element itself, so you need to access the `value` then call `parseInt()` to convert it to a number.

For task #2, you can listen for clicks in the box div, but you need to have your p clicks call `stopPropagation()` so that their clicks don't bubble to the div, preventing your score from changing.

Modified code below:

```js
var windowHeight = 0;
var parendElement;
var gameStarted = false;
var clicks;

function startg() {
  parendElement = document.getElementById("box");
  gameStarted = true;
  windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
  document.body.style.height = windowHeight + "px";
  clicks = parseInt(document.getElementById('scores').value)

  parendElement.onclick = function() {
    if (gameStarted) {
      document.getElementById('scores').value = --clicks;
    }
  };

  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    generateBall();
  }, 1000);
};

function generateBall() {
  var leftPos = Math.floor((Math.random() * window.innerWidth) - 30);
  var topPos = Math.floor((Math.random() * windowHeight) - 30);
  var para = document.createElement("p");
  para.style.left = leftPos + "px";
  para.style.top = topPos + "px";
  para.setAttribute("class", 'circle');
  para.onclick = function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    document.getElementById('scores').value = ++clicks;
    console.log('clicks');
  };
  parendElement.appendChild(para);
  removeBall(para);
}

function removeBall(ele) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    parendElement.removeChild(ele);
  }, 1000);
}
```

```css
.circle {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blueviolet;
}
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
#box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.score {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
input[type=text] {
  padding: 5px 5px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 90px;
}
button {
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="score">
    <button onclick="startg()">Start Game</button>
    <label for="scores"><b>Score</b>
    </label>
    <input type="text" value="0" name="scores" id="scores">
  </div>
  <div id="box"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Working gud for task one.. Got idea for task two.. I'll create that.. Thanks :)

Comment: Fast? I didn't even have my coffee yet, but thanks. :) @PrasathV, you're welcome. Task #2 should be pretty simple to add, but just be aware of event propagation when trying to capture misclicks.

Comment: I'm getting this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'valueOf' of null` and input field shows `NaN` @xorspark

Comment: Check your markup? Also, are you running after the document has fully loaded or in the head before the markup occurs?. Works fine in the snippet.

Comment: I moved the clicks value initialization into the start game method and added how to accomplish #2.

Comment: its `.value` not `.valueOf`

Comment: Right. I mentioned that but didn't update the code itself.

Answer (score 2):

You have created the `p` element but you didn't added the **click event** to it which causes for the

Add this to the **generateBall** Methods

```
 para.onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById('scores').value = ++clicks;
    console.log('clicks');
  };
```

So here is the working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Kri4shna/uLz9m2kj/)

Comment: @prasath just a small suggestion try to add `cursor:pointer` for class circle will change the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change input value after each click. So in function generateBall just add :

```
document.getElementById('scores').value = clicks;
```

Hope this helps.